# how to bind image path to image upload control after postback in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm trying to bind that image path to image upload control (after page refresh) which was saved in session as well as in viewstate but something is missing and not able to handle that thing...session and viewstate having correct path stored but not getting bind. only this thing need to solve...

Getting exception of Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'.

fuUploadLogo is my image upload control and second last line is not able to bind the path which is in session to fileupload control.

asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadLogo" runat="server"

```
        if (Session["PicturePath1"] == null)
        {
            Session["PicturePath1"] = ViewState["PicturePath"].ToString();
        }
        else if (Session["PicturePath1"] != null)
        {
            fuUploadLogo = (FileUpload)Session["PicturePath1"];                
        }
```

Comment: I suggest you include all code... so we can try figure out what you are trying to do. also Plz change your 'else if' to 'else'. When you set the session value its a string then later you cast to FileUpload is that legit?

Comment: i'm just trying to bind the path having in Session["PicturePath1"] to image upload control. need that code to do so.

Comment: ...and what i am saying is... you are using terminology that makes sense to you. By giving the actual code we will be able to see what you are trying to archive without having to understand how you describe it. If that is what you need, then 'do it'.... what i am suggesting is if you want help, more info is needed. imageControl.ImageUrl = "your url". again with the actual code it is easier to see what is going on. But if someone else is able to help you then cool.

Comment: my second last line in code(fuUploadLogo = (FileUpload)Session["PicturePath1"];) is not able to bind that value in session to fileupload control. i need another code to bind it on this control value is getting correct but not getting bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should need to add image control to view your image,ex:

In aspx, add

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
```

And in aspx.cs

```
Image1.ImageUrl=Convert.ToString(ViewState["PicturePath"]);
```

Comment: thanks for support but i'm using File upload control of ASP.  <asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploadLogo" runat="server" />

Comment: Yes, i know that you are using fileupload control, but to display image you need to use image control, please go thorough this, may this will help you http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2011/01/20/uploading-image-to-a-folder-and-display-the-image-after.aspx

Comment: Sorry but i need to bind path on fileupload not on image control as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload1" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>

         //If first time page is submitted and we have file in FileUpload control but not in session 
        // Store the values to SEssion Object 
        if (Session["PicturePath"] == null && FileUpload1.HasFile)  
        { 
            Session["PicturePath"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; 
        } 
        // Next time submit and Session has values but FileUpload is Blank 
        // Return the values from session to FileUpload 
        else if (Session["PicturePath"] != null && (! FileUpload1.HasFile)) 
        { 
            FileUpload1 = (FileUpload) Session["PicturePath"]; 

        } 
        // Now there could be another sictution when Session has File but user want to change the file 
        // In this case we have to change the file in session object 
        else if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
        { 
            Session["PicturePath"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; 

        }
```

Comment: still this is not working for my requirement. it is getting value correctly but not able to bind it on file upload control.

Comment: i'm getting exception on this line  fuUploadLogo = (FileUpload)Session["PicturePath"]; that Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'.